# Divide a string line

Tags: php, string

For example, I have:

```
$t = 'wap long text[dv]netlong text';
```

I want to divide the string from [dv] to get each parts. My expected result should be:

```
$part ='wap long text';
$part2 ='netlong text';
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe you overlooked `explode()` in the php manual?  Watch the rep flies swarm on this low hanging fruit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
$t = 'wap long text[dv]netlong text';
list($part1, $part2) = explode('[dv]', $t);

// $part1 is 'wap long text'
// $part2 is 'netlong text'
```

Run it [here](https://eval.in/922715).

Comment: Btw, this is safe even if there is no`[dv]` in the string - only `$part2` will be empty in such case.

Comment: what if there are 2 or more occurrences of `[dv]`?

Comment: @Cashbee it will take the first 2 anyways. Anything beyond that is not explicitly specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP `explode()` function for that. Btw, try to google such things for the next time. That could have been found in a few seconds.

```
<?php
$t = 'wap long text[dv]netlong text';
$test = explode("[dv]", $t);
var_dump($test);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$t = 'wap long text[dv]netlong text';

$data=explode('[dv]',$t);


$i=0;
foreach($data as $row){
    $newArray['part'.$i]=$row;
    $i++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
```

This will work dynamic no matter how long is the script it will split it in [dv] and store it's parts into array fields that are named dynamically using the counter value.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [part0] => wap long text
    [part1] => netlong text
)
```

Read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$t = 'wap long text[dv]netlong text';
$t_new = explode('[dv]',$t);
echo $t_new[0].'<br>'.$t_new[1];
```